# How to map a function to all sub-parts of an expression, except sub-parts passing some test

Tags: evaluation, expression-manipulation, functional-style

I'm constructing a function `mapAllExcept` which is similar to `MapAll`:

- It maps a function `f` onto subparts of an expression
- It maps the function `f` to "deeper levels in a given sub-expression first"
- It plays nicely with expressions involving `Hold` attributes **(this is the part I'm having trouble with)**

The difference is that rather than mapping to all subparts, `mapAllExcept` will not apply to subparts of any sub-expression which passes a given `testQ`.

Example:  Replace all instances of `List` with `myList`, unless a sub-expression already has head `myList`, in which case leave that sub-expression alone.  So

```
mapAllExcept[ Replace[List[x___]:>myList[x] ], {{1,2}, myList@{3,4}}, MatchQ[_List] ]

(* myList[   myList[1,2], myList[{3,4}]   ] *)
```

Is there a simple or elegant way to do this?

---

### My Attempt

My approach was to perform a recursive tree traversal, continuing unless the current sub-tree matches `testQ`.  Since the function `f` needs map to deeper subparts first, the initial tree traversal instead maps a 'dummy function' `fdummy`, which has a downvalue `fdummy[x : Except[_fdummy]] := f[x]`.  The recursive traversal is done with a helper function `$mapAllExcept`.

Here's my code:

```
ClearAll[mapAllExcept, $mapAllExcept]

SetAttributes[$mapAllExcept, HoldAll];

(* Map f to all specified parts of expr, except subparts of any part \
on which testQ is True *)
(* Evaluate sub-parts first, as in Map or MapAll *)

mapAllExcept[f_, expr_, testQ_] /; testQ[expr] := expr
mapAllExcept[f_, expr_, testQ_] :=
 Module[{fdummy = Unique@"f"},
  SetAttributes[fdummy, HoldAllComplete];
  fdummy[arg : Except[_fdummy]] := f[arg];
  $mapAllExcept[fdummy, expr, testQ]
 ]

$mapAllExcept[f_, expr_, testQ_] /; testQ[expr] := expr 
    (* I'm worried this will cause premature evaluation of expr, 
        but that's a higher order issue *)

$mapAllExcept[f_, expr_, testQ_] := 
  Replace[expr, x_ :> $mapAllExcept[f, x, testQ], {1}] // f
```

This code fails most of the tests below involving `Hold` attributes.  I've tried some extensions, but they haven't fixed all my problems.

---

### Tests

A correct implementation of `mapAllExcept` should satisfy some conditions:

#### A few simple cases

`mapAllExcept[Replace[x_List :> myList @@ x], #, MatchQ[_myList]]&` should generate the following transformations:

```
AssociationMap[
 mapAllExcept[Replace[x_List :> myList @@ x], #, MatchQ[_myList]] &,
 { myList@{3, 4}, {myList@{3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, myList@{3, 4}} } ]
```

yields (correctly)

```
 <|myList[{3, 4}] -> myList[{3, 4}], 
  {myList[{3, 4}]} -> myList[myList[{3, 4}]], 
  {{1, 2}, myList[{3, 4}]} -> 
      myList[myList[1, 2], myList[{3, 4}]] |>
```

#### When `testQ` always fails

`mapAllExcept[f, expr, False&]` should give identical output to `MapAll[f,expr]` for any `f` and `expr`.  In particular, this should hold for `expr` such as `Hold[1+1,2+2]`.  The above implementation fails:

```
Hold[1 + 1, 2 + 2]
mapAllExcept[ff, %, False &]
(* ff[Hold[$mapAllExcept[fdummy$11580, 1 + 1, False &], $mapAllExcept[
     fdummy$11580, 2 + 2, False &]]] *)
MapAll[ff, %%]
(* ff[Hold[ff[ff[1] + ff[1]], ff[ff[2] + ff[2]]]] *)
```

Again, the above outputs would be identical for a correct implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to manually traversing the expression consider working with lists of positions.

```
positionExcept[expr_, test_, param___] :=
  With[{p = Position[expr, _?test, param]},
    If[p === {{}}, {},
      Position[expr, _, param] //
        DeleteCases[Alternatives @@ ({#, ___} & @@@ p)]
    ]
  ]

Options[mapAllExcept] = {Heads -> False};    

mapAllExcept[f_, expr_, test_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
  MapAt[f, expr, positionExcept[expr, test, Heads -> OptionValue[Heads]]]
```

Test:

```
mapAllExcept[
  Replace[List[x___] :> myList[x]],
  {{1, 2}, myList@{3, 4}},
  MatchQ[_myList]
]
```

> ```
> myList[myList[1, 2], myList[{3, 4}]]
> ```

```
AssociationMap[
 mapAllExcept[Replace[x_List :> myList @@ x], #, 
   MatchQ[_myList]] &, {myList@{3, 4}, {myList@{3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, myList@{3, 4}}}]
```

> ```
> <|myList[{3, 4}] -> myList[{3, 4}], {myList[{3, 4}]} -> 
>   myList[myList[{3, 4}]], {{1, 2}, myList[{3, 4}]} -> 
>   myList[myList[1, 2], myList[{3, 4}]]|>
> ```

```
Hold[1 + 1, 2 + 2];
mapAllExcept[ff, %, False &]
```

> ```
> ff[Hold[ff[ff[1] + ff[1]], ff[ff[2] + ff[2]]]]
> ```

Comment: Ah, I see; I misread that.  I'll put in a quick fix that hopefully doesn't break something else.  I am about to leave so if I mess it up I'll have to revisit it later.  Looks like I'll need `Heads -> False` in `Position` to match the defaults.

Comment: Replacing `Position[expr, _]` with `Position[expr, _, Heads->False]` seems to work perfectly!  +1

Comment: @jjc385 Okay, I added `Heads` as an option, defaulting to `False`, so you can use `mapAllExcept[. . . Heads -> True]` if needed, just like `MapAll`.